# JAX-RPC runtime for Tomcat

Tags: tomcat6, jax-rpc

I have ported a Java EE web application from JBoss 4.0.5/Java 5 to Tomcat 6.0.33/Java 6.

The web application exposes some web services. They were implemented as JAX-RPC web services in JBoss, I have adapted them as JAX-WS web services using CXF 2.6 as the implementation run-time. Now I have been requested to make available in the new environment (Tomcat 6.0.33/Java 6) also the JAX-RPC web services for compatibility with existing clients. The two versions of the same web services would of course be available through two different end point URLs.

The JAX-RPC web services in JBoss 4.0.5/Java 5 are implemented using Spring (the implementation class  extends org.springframework.remoting.jaxrpc.ServletEndpointSupport, found in spring-remoting-2.0.8.jar) but I cannot guess which is the underlaying implementation framework for JAX-RPC made available by JBoss. I just can see that the configuration files are webservices.xml and jaxrpc-mapping.xml.

I tried to "replicate" that Spring configuration in Tomcat but when I try to retrieve the WSDL I get an error `javax.servlet.ServletException: Class pack.age.MyEndPoint is not a Servlet`. Indeed that class (the JAX-RPC end point implementation class) is not a servlet but under JBoss 4.0.5/Java 5 it is declared in `web.xml` as a servlet and it works.

Could you please help? I imagine I just have to supply the proper JAX-RPC implementation framework to Tomcat (I would like to avoid AXIS because it uses different configuration files). Thanks in advance.